# BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEREPLICA throws "no update (test mode)"

Tags: c#, abap, sap-erp, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

I am calling BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEREPLICA  for updating the material in SAP through my WCF Web service using Net connector 3.0 in C#.

Before i was getting the validation errors but after populating all validations now i am getting return message

> Material successfully checked: no update (test mode)

If Is it because of missing parameters then how can i find which parameter is missing

or do i need to set the testing mode on somewhere in C# code or ABAP .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have set the parameter `TESTRUN` to `'X'`. The system is doing just what you specified: Check the data, but do not update anything. If you want to change the data for real, remove the flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot of your help you are a star.